# Is is better to add fragments to an activity by <fragment> tags in xml or by FragmentManager in a code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've started developing Android apps and I am wondering which way is better in case of adding fragments to activity. Let's assume that view for activity contain always three fragments. They won't changed. Always be the same. Thus is it better to add them by  tags or include them in the activity code?

And a second question issue:
Let's say I have activity with fragment which is a list. Then when I clicked on item I want to show new view. Can I then replace the list fragment with new completely different fragment? Even if the answer is yes then is it better than creating new activity?

Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 5):

> which way is better in case of adding fragments to activity

One approach is not necessarily 'better' than the other - they both serve their own purposes, as with any *static vs. dynamic* comparison.

For example, fragments declared in a layout cannot be given arguments using `setArguments()`. Such a fragment can also not be replaced by another fragment: if it's part of the layout, it'll always be there. Of course you can still show/hide the instance, but attempting to actually remove it through a `FragmentTransaction` will simply not work. Static elements are usually easier to work with though, because they have a well-defined lifetime and behaviour.

Regarding your second question: yes, that's very possible. Some developers build their app around a single `Activity` container, swapping out fragments as the user navigates its way through the content. In most cases, from a user's point of view, there is little difference between doing this or having multiple activities. The important thing to keep in mind is to choose an approach you're comfortable with, doesn't overly complicate things and takes advantage of the patterns explained in [Implementing Effective Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html).